# Using Renderscript convolution on a specific location of bitmap

Tags: android, matlab, bitmap, renderscript

In matlab there is an option for doing 2D convolutions, that you can use it so you can have each area where convolution happened. for example if you have done a 3x3 convolution you can say that save the result of each 3x3 window and use it. the command is like this:

```
X = conv2(A,B,'same');
```

the 'same' keyword is going to return the central part of the convolution of the same size as A.
I want to know is there anyway were i can do something like this with renderscript in android? I will put a picture from matlab documentation so you can get a better understding of what i mean. again the picture is **from matlab documentation** wich is free.

[image: The same keyword for a 2D convolution of matlab]

Comment: @cmaster11 can you please help with it?

Comment: @LarrySchiefer can you please help with it if you can? You are one of the few ones who i see in the stackoverflow that answers renderscript questions.

Comment: thank you for the notice :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Script.LaunchOptions` class.

Using this class you can set limits of execution of kernels.

**Example**: you want to run a kernel on a "rectangle" of your data (so, in 2 dimensions), starting at **x**-index (0-based, inclusive) `3` and ending at the x-index (exclusive) `8` and, on the **y** side the limits are `11` and `22`:

```
Script.LaunchOptions launchOptions;
launchOptions = new Script.LaunchOptions();
launchOptions.setX(3, 8);
launchOptions.setY(11, 22);

// Kernel run
myScript.forEach_myKernelName(inAlloc, outAlloc, launchOptions);
```

**Example**: you want to apply a kernel over an image, with a 3-pixel-wide border (example directly taken from the [FASTExample](https://bitbucket.org/cmaster11/rsbookexamples/src/tip/FASTExample/) sample project):

```
Script.LaunchOptions fastLaunchOptions;
fastLaunchOptions = new Script.LaunchOptions();
fastLaunchOptions.setX(3, inputImageSize.width - 3);
fastLaunchOptions.setY(3, inputImageSize.height - 3);

// ...

scriptCFast.forEach_fastOptimized(
      grayAllocation, fastKpAllocation, fastLaunchOptions);
```

**Example**: you want to apply a `ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3` kernel over a restricted range:

```
// Define the convolution
ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3 convolve3x3 =
    ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3.create(mRS, Element.RGBA_8888(mRS));

// Some coefficients
float[] coefficients = {
        0.7f, 0, 0.5f,
        0, 1.0f, 0,
        0.5f, 0, 1.0f
};
convolve3x3.setCoefficients(coefficients);

// Execute the allocation with limits
Script.LaunchOptions launchOptions;
launchOptions = new Script.LaunchOptions();
launchOptions.setX(3, 8);
launchOptions.setY(11, 22);

convolve3x3.setInput(inputAllocation);
convolve3x3.forEach(convolvedAllocation, launchOptions);
```

**Note**: this process just executes a kernel over a certain range, but it is NOT going to create a new, smaller allocation. So, after having executed a kernel over certain limits, you should copy the result of it using a copy kernel, like the following one:

```
// Store the input allocation
rs_allocation inputAllocation;

// Offset indices, which define the start point for 
// the copy in the input allocation.
int inputOffsetX;
int inputOffsetY;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) copyAllocation(int x, int y) {

    return rsGetElementAt_uchar4(
         inputAllocation, x + inputOffsetX, y + inputOffsetY);

}
```

Invoked with:

```
scriptC_main.set_inputAllocation(convolvedAllocation);
scriptC_main.set_inputOffsetX(offsetX);
scriptC_main.set_inputOffsetY(offsetY);
scriptC_main.forEach_copyAllocation(outputAllocation);
```

**Edit**: I specifically created an [example](https://bitbucket.org/cmaster11/rsbookexamples/src/tip/LimitedConvolutionExample/) for this case, where you can see the following process:

- Execution of a limited convolution, over a data set.
- Copying of the convolution output to a new Allocation.

Reference: [RenderScript: parallel computing on Android, the easy way](https://hydex11.net/renderscript_parallel_computing_on_android_the_easy_way)

Comment: why the Y boundries are 11 and 22? can you give me a visualize answer?

Comment: And the important thing is that i want to use the convolution 3x3 which is already written for renderscript. can i use the ScriptIntrinsic with this launchoptions?

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand the Y and X boundries. Can you explain more? Or give a visual explanation? I want to iterate over all pixels. From the beginning to the end.

Comment: Sure, I'll explain everything in some small time

Comment: I dont understand how you figured out numbers.

Comment: YOU ARE THE BESTTTTTTTTTTT. AWESOME ANSWER. I wish i could give you 10 likes :D .

Comment: can you give me your email please?
or send me an email: salmani.shahryar@gmail.com

Comment: ;) Thank you really much